# Laravel Difference `between app->bind` and `app->singleton`?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, singleton, facade

I've been trying to figure out what the difference between `app->bind` and `app->singleton` are when setting up a service provider in Laravel. I was under the impression that if I register an `singleton` it would return the same instance of the object each time it was called vs `bind` which would be a new instance.

Here is simple example:

Facade:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class DataFacade extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { 
        return 'Data';
    }
}
```

ServiceProvider:

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class DataServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register() {
        $this->app->singleton('Data', function() {
            return new Data;
        });
    }
}
```

Class:

```
class Data
{
    public $data = [];

    public function get($key)
    {
        return isset($this->data[$key]) ? $this->data[$key] : null;
    }

    public function set($key, $val)
    {
        $this->data[$key] = $val;
    }
}
```

If we do something like:

```
$instance = App::make('Data');
$instance->set('foo', 'foo');

$instance2 = App::make('Data');

echo $instance->get('foo');
echo $instance2->get('foo');
```

And run that we will see the appropriate behavior between `bind` and `singleton` with `foo` being printed out once and then twice respectively. However if we run it through the facade like so:

```
Data::set('test', 'test');
Data::set('cheese', 'cheese');
```

When it's a singleton I would expect both `test` and `cheese` to be available and when it's a `bind` I'm not sure what I would expect to be available via the facade, but it seems like there is no difference.

It's the facade treating everything as a `singleton`?

Comment: You already know the difference!

Comment: You mentioned `bind` -- but your question never directly calls bind.

Comment: But doesn't the facade call the service provider which calls bind?

Comment: @Rob Answer below -- in 4.2 (don't know about earlier versions), it looks like the facade calls $app[$service_name], which in turns calls **make**.  Adding to the confusion, the Facade also has its own layer of singleton storage.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing and doesn't have all the information for someone to answer, but it's a confusing topic, so don't feel bad.  Here's a rundown that may help you better understand, and ask the question you wanted to ask (also, I'm newish to Laravel, so I may be off base with these)

1. The `make` method is used to instantiate objects.  When you say `App::make('Data')` you're telling Laravel to instantiate an object from the class `Data`.
2. There's a caveat to number 1.  If you call `make` **and have already bound the string `Data` to something in the service container**, Laravel will return the service instead.  This may mean Laravel instantiates a new service object, or it may mean Laravel returns a service singleton
3. Whether or not Laravel returns a singleton or an instance for a service depends on **how the service was bound**
4. The `make` method doesn't bind anything
5. You bind services with the application object's `bind` method, defined on the container class with the following method prototype `public function bind($abstract, $concrete = null, $shared = false)`
6. See that third `$shared` parameter?  If that's true your service will return a singleton.  If it's false your service will return instances.
7. The application object's `singleton` method **is a method for binding services**

Re: #7, here's the definition of `singleton`

```
#File: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php
public function singleton($abstract, $concrete = null)
{
    $this->bind($abstract, $concrete, true);
}
```

In your examples above you're binding the service `Data` into the container.  Using a leading case service name is going to cause problems -- `data` would be a better choice.  If your `register` method isn't called for some reason, `make` will still instantiate an object with your global class `Data`

Regarding your Facade -- a Facade is an extra layer of instance/singleton-ness.  Here's the method where the facade class uses the string from `getFacadeAccessor` to return an object from a static call

```
#File: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php
protected static function resolveFacadeInstance($name)
{
    if (is_object($name)) return $name;

    if (isset(static::$resolvedInstance[$name]))
    {
        return static::$resolvedInstance[$name];
    }

    return static::$resolvedInstance[$name] = static::$app[$name];
}
```

So, a facade uses `$app[$name];` to grab a service from the container.  This is `ArrayAccess`, so if we look at the definition of `offsetGet`

```
public function offsetGet($key)
{
    return $this->make($key);
}
```

We see `ArrayAccess` wraps a call to `make`.  This means if you have no bound service, facade access will instantiate an object.  If you have the service bound as a singleton/shared service, facade access will return that singleton.  If you have the service bound as not a singleton/shared service, facade access will instantiate a new object.

**HOWEVER**, the Facade itself will store any object it instantiates inside `static::$resolvedInstance`, and future calls to the facade will return this same instance.  This means Facade access introduces a second singleton implementation.  A service bound as a singleton will be stored on the application object, a service accessed via a facade will be stored as a singleton on the `Facade` class.

Comment: Thanks for that great explanation, that helps clarify things a lot. I was missing the piece about the singleton on the facade. If I understand correctly, referring to my example above so if a facade creates a new instance it will be a singleton which would always just refer to `$instance1` that it creates via the IoC/Service Provider binding? Does that mean that a facade will always "act" as a singleton regardless of whether your service provider is setup as a new instance/singleton? If so, is there a way around it using a Facade? I should add, is there be a scenario where we would want to?

Comment: @Rob -- I'm far from an expert yet, but yes, it looks like a Facade will instantiate an object once, and then always use that same object for method calls, **regardless** of how the container is bound.  You could test this with a service method that does a `return $this`, call the method via a facade, and then do state checks.  My suspicions are this was/is a deliberate decision to avoid performance problems with "services are instances not singletons by default"

Comment: I think facades make confusion here, they always force singleton instead of multiple instances, even if you bind with shared false.