# Manually calling controller method with parameter and still have method injection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, ioc-container, laravel-routing

How can I call a **controller method manually** specifying some input parameters yet still have method injection work for the parameters not specified (example below).

**routes.php**

```
$myController->index($id);
```

**controllers/MyControllerOne.php**

```
class MyControllerOne
{

    public function index($id, MyRequest $request)
    {

    }

}
```

**extra information**
The reason I need this is because I have special information in my routes that determines which controller should be executed such as `/myroute/{data}/{id}`. It's a bit unorthodox but it's a necessary evil given the scope of our system.
Once I resolve within my routes which controller needs to be called I then want to call the method on that controller. `$controllerInstance->index($id)`.

Comment: If it's only for Request, I think you could manually pass this `$this->app->make('Request')`, like so `$controllerIntance->index($id, $this->app->make('Request'))`

Comment: I've made it an answer. If you don't mind, I'd be happy if you accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only for Request, I think you could manually pass this `$this->app->make('Request')`, like so

```
$controllerIntance->index($id, $this->app->make('Request'))
```

Note that you actually don't have to inject Request, since you might as well use `App::make` inside of your controller. But I'm not sure how good this decision is in case of testability and coupling.

**For more info:**

This function resolves 'Request' out of the container, that is instantiates or returns an existing instance (depending of the type of service provider).

Using `make` is described here http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/container (see "Resolving"). I also found this answer helpful, to understanding how the container works https://stackoverflow.com/a/25798288/1627227